# Handling undefined text input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this condition here that checks if the value is undefined

```
console.log("Value: " + typeof getValues('departmentId'))
if (String(getValues('departmentId')) != "" ||
    String(getValues('departmentDesc')) != "" ||
    typeof getValues('departmentId') !== undefined ||
    typeof getValues('departmentDesc') !== undefined){
    dispatch(setIsConfirm(true))
    console.log("Clearing fields || Value: " + getValues('departmentId'))
}
```

But for some reason it still ran even though it is undefined, here is the picture of the
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqA5g.png)

Comment: hint: `typeof` always results in a string

Comment: Assuming you've fixed the issue mentioned above, your if statement will also run if `departmentDesc` is not undefined

Comment: Can you share what the getvalue function is

Comment: Try changing the ```!== undefined``` to ```==undefined```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that typeof returns a string. I solved it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typeof` returns a string. So you need to do this instead:

```
console.log("Value: " + typeof getValues('departmentId'))
if (typeof getValues('departmentId') !== "undefined" || typeof getValues('departmentDesc') !== 'undefined'){
    dispatch(setIsConfirm(true))
    console.log("Clearing fields || Value: " + getValues('departmentId'))
}
```

Also, make sure you really need OR `||` operator and not AND `&&`. Replace it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
  if ((String(getValues('departmentId')) !== "" && typeof getValues('departmentId') !== "undefined") ||
            (String(getValues('departmentDesc')) !== "" && typeof getValues('departmentDesc') !== "undefined")){
            dispatch(setIsConfirm(true))
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add some more detail about how this solved your problem? It might help other people in the future

Comment: Sure. So basically I want to check whether the getValues() returns an undefined and a non empty string or not. I want to check for both deparmentId and departmentDesc and run if either one is true. This works perfectly for me.